# Rail reading external db with unusual table names and column names

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have to read  external db with tables that have unsual names. In one case the table name is "000001.SH" and inside that table the column name is "Open.Price".
I managed to connect to the external db, but I am not sure how to retrieve the table from the controller.

Is there a solution or pure SQL code is the only option ? 
Can I rename  the table and the column on the go ?

Comment: I would create a service object that reads data from the external database and normalizes it to your application.

Answer (score 0):

Create a model with a meaningful name and update `table_name` property like this

```
class Price < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name = "000001.SH"
end
```